# Manipulate array foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have array 1 and it should be 2

Does anyone have an idea / solution?

Do i need foreach or for loop?

1.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 5
        [category] => Pages
    )
```

)

Must be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [5] => Pages
    )
```

)

I have this but this doent work...

```
    for($x = 0; $x <= $counter; $x++){
        foreach ($Categories[$x] as $key => $value){
            echo $key.' '. $value.'<br>';
        }
        $test[$x]['category_id'] .= $Categories[$x]['category'];
    }
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yes you need `foreach`.

Comment: Do you want to `(unset)` the id?

Comment: $arr[$i] = array($arr['category_id'] => $arr['category']); something like this in loop should work I am not sure what exactly you want to get.

Comment: @Robert Podwika Well i am getting 1 from the database and i want to manipulate it "must be"

Comment: @Bas: You code executing in infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    array(
        'category_id' => 5      ,
        'category'    => 'Pages',
    ),
);

$new = array();
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $new[] = array(
        $item['category_id'] => $item['category']
    );
}

print_r($new);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [5] => Pages
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$output=array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
  $output[$v['category_id']]=$v['category'];
}

echo "<pre />";
print_r($output);
```

[Demo1](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/jq2-pxn)

[Demo 2](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/jq2-pxn)

for multidimensinal result :

```
$output=array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
  $output[][$v['category_id']]=$v['category'];
}

echo "<pre />";
print_r($output);
```

Comment: I think @Bas requires multi-dementional result.

Comment: @CertaiN check answer for multidimensional result

Comment: @CertaiN : do not downvote any answer, if it doesn't belong to you or your question

Answer (score 1):

As you said you will need a foreach loop to manupulate you array.

Example

```
$array = array
(
'0' => array
    (
        'category_id' => '5',
        'category' => 'Pages'
    )
);  


$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $val)
{
     $new_array[$val['category_id']] = $val['category'];
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

this will output

```
array(1) { [5]=> string(5) "Pages" }
```